# I am failing to log into most chat rooms

Tags: support, chat

I can log into [Let's get philosophical](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/lets-get-philosophical) and [The Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/the-tavern-general) but no where else (I've tried several rooms).

This problem appears when I use Chromium (both **9** and **10**), but not Firefox (I checked with **3.5**). Output of https://chat.stackexchange.com/help is good (*All tests were successful*).

Comment: What browser? What's the output of http://chat.stackexchange.com/help ?

Comment: @bal question updated.

Comment: have you tried in Chrome Incognito mode, that is, disabling all extensions? Are you changing any of the default browser settings?

Comment: @jeff I tried that and it worked. I then disabled my 2 extensions, and re-enabled one of them (one I actually use), and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: can you add that as an answer and accept it please?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which one of these steps actually got rid of the problem:

1. Logging in any chat worked with Chromium's Incognito mode.
2. I removed one of my Extensions (don't remember the name, but has to do with downloading videos).
3. I disabled the other one ([Personal Block list](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef)) and restarted Chromium.
4. I re-enabled it.